# OCR reconizes stranges characters. Why?

Tags: character, ocr

I'm using OCR to develop an Android Application using the `Tesseract Libs`, with the `tess-two` project, as I saw here: http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

The app worked fine, but I'm repairing that string returned with the content of a photo, sometimes, comes with strangers characters. Example: I'm reading this: `www.caelum.com.br` and receiving something like this: `r ' . ,wlñzf . 94' kzl 5. vsmNs/.caelumcombr` 
Searching, I've configured this: `baseApi.setVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");` 
But I think that becomes worst.

I want to read texts in Portuguese and English. So, I downloaded the traineddata for each language and using it as I wish, but these strangers characters have something to do with the encoding project ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: try to set "tessedit_char_blacklist" to "':;,.?/\\}][{!@#$%^&*()-_=+~" with the use of baseApi.setVariable(). May this will help you to get read of the unwanted character. You can add more characters to the string which you don't want to recognize or reject by tesserect ocr

Comment: First of all, sorry for the delay. So, I tried to set this blacklist and became a little better, but studying more about Tesseract I discover that treat the image, to make it with better quality, helps too. So I'm using the own Tesseract project eyes-two, that contains methods to do that and now, it works much better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract recognizes text only for images that contains text and only text. Images that contains only text will be accurately recognized by it and you can get good accuracy too.
However Tesseract gives garbled output for image + text recognition. 
  I didn't worked on this recognition so can't help further.

So your question should be as to how to crop the image part so that you get only the text part out from image. Like that Tesseract can recognize fine and give desired text in ouput.

Thanks.

Comment: Once again, sorry for the delay. As I said above I'm using the blacklist with Tesseract project eyes-two, that contains methods to treat the images and works much better now. In addition I'm doing the image crop too. This worked for me and now I have better results. Thanks for your help too :)